# Is HtmlUnit would execute JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, kerberos, htmlunit

We are hitting a URL Ex: `https:/xyz.com` with `WebClient` (having *Kerberos authentication*), which has **SSO** authentication due to this its redirecting to **idp**.

When we print the page its showing **idp** redirection page instead of the actual page and it contains one JavaScript function. After this we thought to execute the script with `HtmlUnit`, but its not allowing to get the proper page.

We have tried many suggested ways but still no positive result, don't know what is missing. Could you please help to execute the JavaScript in `HtmlUnit`?

Comment: Please use latest version and provide your complete case (with the URL).

Comment: Thanks for the update on this ,Is 2.25 is the latest version? because we are using 2.24 version.

Comment: Hava look at http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ i guess you are able to figure out what the latest version is ;-)

Comment: okay, I could see :the  latest release on February 23, 2017 is **version 2.25** , If possible could you please share a sample code considering the above informed scenario - thanks

Comment: In general: If the HtmlUnit behavior is different from the browser this is a bug. But as long as you can't provide test case visible for us we can not do much for you. So please provide as many details as possible and your expectations. Try to start by figuring out what the real browsers are doing (using Charles Proxy or Fiddler) and than compare it with the way HtmlUnit handles your pages.

Comment: `<html><head><title>sample</title></head>
<body><form action='/fo' name='form'>
      <script eval="true">
      setTimeout(function() {
        top.location.assign('https://www.example.ch/' + location.hash);
      });
      </script>
  </form></body></html>`
above is the sample script,to execute it are using following
`HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
ScriptResult results = page.executeJavaScript(page.getByXPath("//script").toString());
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60 * 1000);
page=(HtmlPage) result.getNewPage();
System.out.println(page.asXml());`

Comment: We are trying to hit a local URL in that some JavaScript is there,

If we able to execute the JavaScript function(which has a link) successfully,
then when we print (page.asXml()) the final/new page,the expecting result is, the page should contain the result of  (https://www.example.ch/)  link.
Could you please help on this- thanks

Comment: After few days,I came to know why it was failing to execute the JavaScript,now we are able to execute the JavaScript

still not getting the proper page after redirection,this is due SSO/SAML as following steps
1) Hitting the URL`https:/xyz.com` then getting the JavaScript which will post SAMLRequest
2) After executing the JavaScript,we should get the Home page of `xyz.com`,but it is going to IdP and getting page of "Page Expired" 
3) Not sure why the session getting expired..do we need to setup/handle any cookies or session object to get the Proper page?

Could you please help on this.